# Why is the coordinate vector of a linear combination equal to a linear combination of coordinate vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook reads:

"Let $S$ be a basis for a vector space $V$.

For any $\boldsymbol{v}_1,\boldsymbol{v}_2,...,\boldsymbol{v}_r \in V$ and $c_1, c_2, ..., c_r \in \mathbb{R}$,

$(c_1\boldsymbol{v}_1 + c_2\boldsymbol{v}_2+...+c_r\boldsymbol{v}_r)_S=c_1(\boldsymbol{v}_1)_S+c_2(\boldsymbol{v}_2)_S+...+c_r(\boldsymbol{v}_r)_S$"

where $(\boldsymbol{v})_S$ is the coordinate vector of $\boldsymbol{v}$ relative to $S$.

Is there an obvious reason why this is true? I know it is true by writing out both sides explicitly (which was quite tedious), but it seems there is a simple reason why it is true because the textbook calls it a "Remark", not a "Theorem", and just mentions it without proof.

(Note: the textbook defines a vector space as some $V$ such that "either $V=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, for some $n$ ", and defines $V$ is to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if $V$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $V=span(S)$, where $S=\{u_{1},u_2,...,u_k\} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious reason is that the map from $v$ to $(v)_S$ is a homomorphism. Informally, we say that it respects the vector space operations, meaning that $(c·v)_S = c·v_S$ and $(v+w)_S = v_S+w_S$ for any scalar $c$ and vectors $v,w$. You can easily prove these two facts, and hence by the obvious induction you can obtain your textbook's statement.

More abstractly, a homomorphism from a structure to another (in this case from a vector space to another) commutes with the structure's operations. Informally, scale-then-map is the same as map-then-scale, and add-then-map is the same as map-then-add. This is how one should think of homomorphisms.

By the way, your textbook is **wrong** in its definition of [vector space](http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-VS.html)! For example, functions on the real numbers **are** a vector space over the reals, and it is in no way evident that this vector space has a basis!

Comment: My textbook uses a simplified definition of vector spaces, rather than the "proper" definition of a vector space (over a field with addition and mutiplication etc.), that's why I made that note

Comment: @Sol: In my opinion, one should not use a term wrongly. It is fine to simplify, but then it should be called [Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) to be consistent with the standard terminology.

Comment: I agree. Correct usage also avoids the later need to learn the correct definition and forget this wrong one. But I just pointed it out because the textbook was using that definition.

Comment: @Sol: Yup I understand!

Answer (score 0):

We have $\mathbf{v}_{i}=S\left(\mathbf{v}_{i}\right)_{S}$ where I denote by $S$ the matrix with the basis vectors as columns.
Thus $$S\left(\sum_{i}c_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\right)_{S}=\sum_{i}c_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}=\sum_{i}c_{i}S\left(\mathbf{v}_{i}\right)_{S}=S\sum_{i}c_{i}\left(\mathbf{v}_{i}\right)_{S}$$
As the images of $\left(\sum_{i}c_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\right)_{S}$ and $\sum_{i}c_{i}\left(\mathbf{v}_{i}\right)_{S}$ are the same under basis-multiplication, the two terms need to be equal.